# What are the performance considerations when adding a large number of documents to a large Solr core?

Tags: performance, solr

If I have a Solr core with a half-dozen small fields that's loaded with 100 million documents, will adding a batch of 1 million documents run in a reasonable amount of time?  How about 10 million? By reasonable, I'm thinking hours, rather than days.  I've been told that this will take a long time to run.  Is this really an issue?  What are known strategies to improve performance?  The fields are typically small, that is, 5-50 characters.

Comment: More than one good answer here, but I have to pick one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very "tricky" question whose answer differs from schema to schema.

1. Your solr installation has a half-dozen fields. But, how many are actually indexed? If only one field is indexed, then adding 1 million documents will be faster than adding 1 million docs when 6 fields are indexed.
2. I think the type of fields that are indexed also matters. A field that is of the type "text_general" is broken down into tokens while indexing whereas a field that is of the type "string" is not. "String" type is not analyzed and is stored as one complete token.
3. I have got some very long fields which are indexed and adding 2 million docs take a few minutes (although my installation does not contain 100 million documents). So, I do not think that it will take days to add 10 million records to your installation.
4. I am not sure about this but maybe the configuration of your cpu which is running the solr instance also matters. So, you might need to see if you cpu and memory can handle this much load.

It's upto you to decide if a long running data post is an issue or not. If your application is user intensive, then I suggest that you follow some kind of master-slave configuration so that the user is not impacted by the high cpu usage when you post the data. Some strategies which I know about improving performance is "sharding".

http://carsabi.com/car-news/2012/03/23/step-by-step-solr-sharding/

or if it is possible to demarcate the records by some field and put those different documents onto different servers.

Comment: The key is indexed, and all of the other fields are sent through LowerCaseFilterFactory, and the lowercased version of each is indexed.  In short, they're all indexed.  We're using this to provide searching on data loaded into HBase.

Comment: In that case, you can consider sharding and split up the index. Question though :- are all the fields returned back to the user? or are only a certain number of fields returned back?

Comment: When a user does a search on one or more of the fields, the complete document would be returned, and that includes an index back into the HBase database.

Answer (score 2):

two suggestions on top of already mentioned in other answers for improving the performance (first tried, second to be tried):

1) decrease logging while updating: on INFO level SOLR appends one entry per document. See here on how we did it: http://dmitrykan.blogspot.fi/2011/01/solr-speed-up-batch-posting.html Some people reported "x3 speed increase".

2) set the amount of segments in solrconfig.xml to something very large for indexing, like 10000. Once the batch indexing is complete, change the parameter value back to something reasonably low, like 10.

Comment: About option 2 - in our use case this would require that we could programmatically change this value before loading a batch and set it back after.  There's aalso the possibility of overlapping batches, so that would have to be managed.  What's the impact of leaving it high all the time?

Comment: leaving it high will impact the search performance. But, again, it is better to test first.

Answer (score 1):

100 million records is a fairly large index for Solr. But adding 10 million records on a good machine should be hours not days. You may find t[he following email thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/DIH-fails-after-processing-roughly-10million-records-td4031508.html) interesting as it includes both in-depth questions and some final advice on tuning for 10M records index process.

Also, you did not say if you 'store' the fields as well as index them. If you do, you may also look forward to [Solr 4.1 field compression](http://solr.pl/en/2012/11/19/solr-4-1-stored-fields-compression/).

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  We store the fields in the same case as submitted, and index on the lower-cased version.  We do not store the lower-case version.

Answer (score 0):

An important parameter which impacts the indexing performance(in terms of Time) is the way in which you have defined your **data-config.xml** file.

If your fields come from **multiple tables** in a Database, you can configure it in 2 ways:

- [Entities within entities](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example)
- A single entity with a join query

**The second method is comparatively faster** than the first one by a large degree because the number of queries fired against the database is decreased.